# How to merge two vertex in one?

Tags: mesh

[image]

I selected the 4 vertex and i pressed f but now i have the problem that i want just 2 of that 4 vertex but even if i press "limited dissolve" or "Remove doubles" it doesnt do what i want, in the worst of the cases it ends all broke xD help pls!

Comment: Select the vertices you want then use "Alt + M" (to merge) and in the panel that appears, select the way you want them to be merged.

Comment: Sometimes I prefer scaling them all the way down to 0 `S`->`0` and hit `W`->`remove doubles`. It's easier to reach on the keyboard and works perfectly well.